# Excel VBA: How to pull subfolders that contain a specific year in its name e.g. subfolders starting with "2020." and also stop at that tree level

Tags: excel, vba, list, directory, filesystemobject

Trying to adapt this code below to

1. show me only subfolders that start with "2020"
2. only show me subfolders at that level (so don't need subfolders within those subfolders as right now this loops and gives me the subfolders within the subfolders)

Fixed the typo below:

Answer (score 0):

if 2020 already included in subfolder-names, perhaps try
with a function left ...

rgds

Answer (score 0):

```vb
'lists information about the folders in SourceFolder
' example: ListSubFolders "C:", "2020*"
Sub ListSubFolders(SourceFolderName As String, Optional pattern as string="")  
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject 
    Dim sf As Scripting.Folder, c As Range

    Set c = sheets("Folders").Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlup).offset(1,0)
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    For Each sf In FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName).SubFolders
        If Len(pattern)=0 or SourceFolder.Name Like pattern Then
        ' display folder properties
        c.Resize(1, 7).Value= Array( _
                     sf.Path, sf.Name, sf.Size, sf.SubFolders.Count, _
                     sf.Files.Count, sf.ShortName, sf.ShortPath)
        End If
        Set c = c.offset(1, 0)
    Next SubFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! it seems to have an issue with "rw" - what does that mean in this case? do we need to define it?

Comment: Sorry - my typo - fixed above

Comment: Thank you - a couple of errors came up - it said to define SourceFolder and SubFolder so I added Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, SubFolder As Scripting.Folder but now its given an error on "Next Subfolder" and says "compile error, Invalid next control variable reference". Any idea on how to fix that? thank you again, not too knowledgable about VBA so trying to understand what's going on